# Vertically offset stem plot

Tags: matlab, plot

How do I vertically offset a `stem` plot so that the stems emanate from say y == 0.5 instead of from the x-axis?

I know I could change the x-tick-marks but it would be better to rather just change the plot.

`stem(X+0.5)` doesn't work as it will just make the stems longer.

Also I have both positive and negative data. And also I have other plots on the same axis which I don't want to offset.

---

Based on Luis Mendo's answer below, I have written a function for this (however see [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24865554/1011724) as MATLAB actually has a built-in property for this anyway):

```
function stem_offset(x_data, y_data, offset, offset_mode, varargin)
%STEM_OFFSET stem plot in which the stems begin at a position vertically
%offset from the x-axis.
%
%   STEM_OFFSET(Y, offset) is the same as stem(Y) but offsets all the lines
%   by the amount in offset
%
%   STEM_OFFSET(X, Y, offset) is the same as stem(X,Y) but offsets all the
%   lines by the amount in offset
%
%   STEM_OFFSET(X, Y, offset, offset_mode) offset_mode is a string
%   specifying if the offset should effect only the base of the stems or
%   also the ends. 'base' for just the base, 'all' for the baseand the
%   ends. 'all' is set by default
%
%   STEM_OFFSET(X, Y, offset, offset_mode, ...) lets call all the stem()
%   options like colour and linewidth etc as you normally would with
%   stem().

    if nargin < 3
        offset = 1:length(y_data);
        y_data = x_data;
    end
    if nargin < 4
        offset_mode = 'all';
    end

    h = stem(x_data, y_data, varargin{:});
    ch = get(h,'Children');

    %Offset the lines
    y_lines = get(ch(1),'YData'); %// this contains y values of the lines

    %Offset the ends
    if strcmp(offset_mode, 'all')
        set(ch(1),'YData',y_lines+offset)
        y_ends = get(ch(2),'YData'); %// this contains y values of the ends
        set(ch(2),'YData',y_ends+offset) 
    else
        set(ch(1),'YData',y_lines+offset*(y_lines==0)) %// replace 0 (i.e. only the start of the lines) by offset
    end

end
```

Which I have now uploaded to the file exchange (http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/45643-stem-plot-with-offset)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that there actually is a property in `stem` for this that I somehow missed!

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/stem.html#btrw_xi-87

e.g. from the docs:

```
figure
X = linspace(0,2*pi,50)';
Y = (exp(0.3*X).*sin(3*X));
h = stem(X,Y);
set(h,'BaseValue',2);
```

Answer (score 3):

The following seems to work. Apparently, the `stem` object's first child contains the vertical lines, so you just have to change all 0 values in their `YData` property to the desired offset:

```
delta = .5; %// desired offset
h = stem(1:10); %// plot to be offset. Get a handle

ch = get(h,'Children');
yy = get(ch(1),'YData'); %// this contains y values of the lines
set(ch(1),'YData',yy+delta*(yy==0)) %// replace 0 by delta
```

---

An example with both positive and negative data, and with other plots on the same axis:

```
stem(.5:4.5,ones(1,5),'g') %// not to be offset
hold on
h = stem(1:5,[-2 3 -4 1 -1]); %// to be offset
axis([0 5.5 -5 4])

ch = get(h,'Children');
yy = get(ch(1),'YData'); %// this contains y values of the lines
set(ch(1),'YData',yy+delta*(yy==0)) %// replace 0 by delta
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Luis, that's perfect. weird that `ch` looks like just a 2-by-1 double vector when debugging though. I've wrapped this into a function, I will add it to my question, have a look.

Comment: @Dan I've made a minor correction (closing parenthesis). Yes, I think it would nice to submit it to File Exchange, as other people may find it useful

Comment: Thanks again. I have submitted it (http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/45643-stem-plot-with-offset)

Answer (score 2):

You can draw a white rectangle over the stems right after you call `stem`.

```
x = 1:10

stem(x)

fudge=0.05
rectangle('Position', [min(x) * range(x)*fudge, 0.5*fudge, range(x)*(1+2*fudge), 0.5-fudge], 'FaceColor', 'w', 'EdgeColor', 'w')
```

The `fudge` is there to avoid painting over the axis, and to make sure the leftmost and rightmost stems are covered.

[image]

Comment: +1 but won't that overwrite previous plots? The question specifies that the figure may contain other plots

Comment: @LuisMendo Yes, it will paint over other plots. You can work around this by drawing the stems first, painting over, and then doing your other plots. You can also modify this method to draw a series of tiny, very skinny rectangles over the individual stems; then the area between stems will not be affected - but really my answer is an unsophisticated, quick and dirty solution.

Comment: Thanks, it's a nice idea but it won't help with stems going in the other direction. +1 anyway, but I'll definitely stick with Luis' method