# Matlab bar plot in specific time points of each measured values

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I want to plot vertical lines corresponding to values obtained at specific time points.

Example:

```
a = [0    5  7    9 ] at 0 seconds, 
b = [0.5  6  6.5  11] at 2 seconds,
c = [0    4  2    10] at 4 seconds
```

Each time point will be a vertical line between the maximum and minimum of the vectors. I also need to mark the start and end points of `a`, `b` and `c`, for instance `a` should have a circle (or star etc.) at 0 and 9.

Here is an example output:

[image: Example Image]

Comment: First you need to take the `min` and `max` of your vectors, the other data seems irrelevant? Then using either [this `scatter`/`line` method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46151836/3978545) to plot lines with end point markers, or [this "floating" `stem` method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21921150/3978545) because all of your lines are vertical, you can make your plot. Please add any code you've tried if you want actual coding help, rather than someone writing it for you from scratch

Comment: @Wolfie thank you for your answer. Scatter/line method helped me alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `line` with end markers.

```
% Your data
a = [0    5   7    9 ];
b = [0.5  6   6.5  11];
c = [0    4   2    10];
% Combine to get min/max values
data = [a; b; c].';
mins = min(data);
maxs = max(data);
% Plot using line, nice flexible method which plots vertical lines at points 2:2:n 
line(repmat(2*(0:numel(mins)-1), 2, 1), [mins; maxs], 'color', 'k', 'marker', 'o')
```

Output:

[image: plot]

---

If you want different markers on each end, or different colours, please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46151836/3978545) which gives more detailed examples.